Formattable in R gridlines
I want to print table with black and solid borders between cells in table.
My code:
library(formattable)

x <- c(1,2,3)
y <- c(5,6,7)
z <- rbind(x,y)
z <- as.data.frame(z)

formattable(z)

I can not find in formattable documentation information about formating cells borders.

install.packages("kableExtra")
library(kableExtra)

# Create the table with borders
kbl(z) %>%
  kable_styling
  (
    "striped", 
    full_width = F,
    position = "center"
  ) %>%
  kable_styling
  (
    bootstrap_options = c("bordered", "hover"), 
    table.attr = "style='border: 2px solid black;'" # Custom border style
  )


I think switching to another package is the easiest option:
data.frame(x = seq(3), y = c(5,6,7)) |>
  # formattable::formattable() |> # line not needed 
  flextable::flextable() |>
  flextable::border_inner() # telling names (functions)

For more
